# iTunes Connect - releasing two binaries in quick succession

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store-connect

I have a binary submitted to the app store and is waiting for review. I have another version of my binary which I want to release as a subsequent version. Is it possible I can upload two binaries with two versions so my users can receive updates in quick succession? I am trying to avoid rejecting the present binary cause then Apple may take longer to review my app and the release will be delayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you can only have one binary in the review queue at a time. You need to wait for Apple to release the first binary, or reject it yourself, before you can upload a new binary.